# eclipse error removing google app engine

Tags: hibernate, google-app-engine, gwt

Hey I got some errors in my gwt project, but now I heart that hibernate is incompatible with the app engine and so I tried to remove the app engine (project->properties->google->app engine->remove checkbox). but now I got this error:

```
An error occurred while saving project properties:

null

see eclipse log for more information.
```

Comment: see eclipse log for more information and post here as well.

Comment: thank you, but we started a new project and removed the app engine first. now there is no error anymore

Comment: I also faced this problem and I did in the same way.